# JavaScript Stopwatch will pause when browser's tab change instead of continuing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript stopwatch on my website that my authors have to use it when they are doing some actions. This actions are depend on using another pages/tabs on my website but currently when my authors going to another tab, the stopwatch will pause and when they return to the page, stopwatch will continue. It is supposed to continue even if they change tabs.

Here is my code:

```js
let startBtn = document.getElementById('start');
let stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop');
let resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
let timeY = document.getElementById('timey');

let minute = 00;
let second = 00;
let count = 00;

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'none';
};

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    timer = true;
    stopWatch();
    
    document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'none';
});

stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    timer = false;
    document.getElementById('start').innerHTML = "Continue";
    document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'inline';
});

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    timer = false;

    minute = 0;
    second = 0;
    count = 0;

    document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "00";
    
    document.getElementById('acf-field_651d01208c082').value = "00:00:00";
});

function stopWatch() {
    if (timer) {
        count++;

        if (count == 100) {
            second++;
            count = 0;
        }

        if (second == 60) {
            minute++;
            second = 0;
        }




        let minString = minute;
        let secString = second;
        let countString = count;



        if (minute < 10) {
            minString = "0" + minString;
        }

        if (second < 10) {
            secString = "0" + secString;
        }

        if (count < 10) {
            countString = "0" + countString;
        }

        document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = minString;
        document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = secString;
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = countString;
        
        document.getElementById('acf-field_651d01208c082').value = minString+":"+secString+":"+countString;
        
        
        setTimeout(stopWatch, 10);
    }
}

jQuery('#acf-group_651d0120348fc').insertAfter('#submitdiv');
```

```css
#acf-field_651d01208c082 {cursor: help;text-align: center;font-family: Vazirmatn UI, sans-serif !important;border: 0px;font-size: 19px;letter-spacing: 4px;background: transparent !important;background: #fff0 !important;}
#buttons #start {background: #4CAF50;color: #FFF;border: 1px solid #4CAF50;}
#buttons #start:hover {background: #409743;color: #FFF;border: 1px solid #4CAF50;}
#buttons #stop {display:none;background: #e73e77;color: #FFF;border: 1px solid #e73e77;}
#buttons #stop:hover {background: #c13b68;color: #FFF;border: 1px solid #e73e77;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timey" style="text-align: center;direction: ltr !important;font-size: 0px !important;font-size: 0.01px !important;visibility: hidden;">
            <span class="digit" id="min">
                00</span>
            <span class="txt">:</span>
            <span class="digit" id="sec">
                00</span>
            <span class="txt">:</span>
            <span class="digit" id="count">
                00</span>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons" style="text-align: center;">
            <button type="button" class="button" id="start">start</button>
            <button type="button" class="button" id="stop" style="display: none;">stop</button>
            <button type="button" class="button" id="reset">reset</button>
        </div>

<input type="text" id="acf-field_651d01208c082" name="acf[field_651d01208c082]" placeholder="00:00:00" readonly="">
```

Comment: have you seen: [How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5927284) ?

Comment: can we use this directly in javascript `let minute = 00; let second = 00; let count = 00;`

Comment: @nick-parsons Yes, but couldn't figured out to fix my code with that. :(

Comment: @Yogi couldn't figured out to fix my code with that

Comment: Don't accumulate a counter. That is anyway a very bad way to count time, even without that "inactive when on other tabs" problem. That way you don't count the time spent in the code for example. So, slow machine will have slower passing time (not in proportion. Since the `timeout` part should be the most important part, and that one should be the same for a slow and a fast machine. But still... there is a time 10+ε ms  between each call. And ε depends on how fast is the client machine.

Comment: Instead, get the start datetime, and current datetime, and compute the difference. And refresh your stopwatch with setTimeout or setInterval as frequently as you want, but the refreshing of the rendering is then unrelated to the measurement.

Comment: @chrslg That is a good idea. I will try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rudimentary example.

`past` accumulate all the past measured interval (the one for which we have, in the past, since last reset, started and then stopped the watch).
`startTime` is the starting time of the current measurement (the date at which we hit 'start' button the last time

So start button just keeps the value of startTime.
And stop button (same, when running) add `now-startTime` to the `past` accumulator.

That's all that is actively done to measure time. Rest (the set interval) is unnecessary and just for rendering (time is measured whether we show it or not).

So, what that `setIterval` function does is just display the `past` accumulator, plus, if needed, the current interval as it would be if we were hitting stop now.

```js
let $start=document.getElementById('startstop');
let $reset=document.getElementById('reset');
let $watch=document.getElementById('acf-field_651d01208c082');

let startTime=false;
let running=false;
let past=0;

$start.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(running){
    running=false;
    $start.textContent='Start';
    let now=new Date();
    past += now-startTime;
  }else{
    running=true;
    $start.textContent='Stop';
    startTime=new Date();
  }
});

$reset.addEventListener('click', function(){
  startTime=new Date();
  past=0;
});

setInterval(function(){
  let total=past;
  if(running){
    total += (new Date())-startTime;
  }
  let h=Math.floor(total/3600000);
  total-=h*3600000;
  let m=Math.floor(total/60000);
  total-=m*60000;
  $watch.value=h+':'+m.toFixed(0).padStart(2,'0')+':'+(total/1000).toFixed(2).padStart(5,'0');
}, 70);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="acf-field_651d01208c082" name="acf[field_651d01208c082]" placeholder="00:00:00" readonly="">
<button id=startstop>Start</button>
<button id=reset>Reset</button>
```

As for "why 70" for the interval... Well, I could have used 10. But, I want to illustrate that this is just rendering. And you don't really need a 100 fps rendering for a stop watch. You eyes are not that accurate. 100 ms, that is 10 fps would be enough. But since we show 2 decimal places, that would lead, to the decimal place to be almost constant (almost, because setInterval is not exactly accurate).

We don't really want that last decimal place to increase every 1/100th of second. We just want it to keep moving really fast, so our eye just see it moving. But we don't want it to appear fixed neither. So not a factor of 100ms. Hence any interval small enough to create running feeling (70 is almost 15 fps) and that does not end by 00 (7 is prime. So last decimal place will show all digits). Well that are some overthinking probably. But my point is: this is only about rendering the time. Whatever interval you choose will not impact how time is measured. If you put '86400000' in there, well, time is still measured as accurately, even if the display is updated only once a day. If you put '10', you are probably spending too much of your cpu time (or rather, your users cpu time) in rendering digits that nobody can possibly read that fast, but still, it doesn't impact how time is measured.

Comment: Thanks. How should I get a time from field and set to `watch` id? I managed to put time with onclick on `startstop` on a field and submit to database. When post updated, page will get submitted time to field but i want to set that time to stopwatch. Stopwatch just showing `0:00:00.00` time everytime page getting refresh but I need to show submitted time if it's available and if there is no time, then it should show `0:00:00.00`. Is this possible?

Comment: May be the easier way is to do the same as in your code: instead of my `<div id=watch>` use directly your `<input>`. And then, when I update `textContent` of `div#watch`, update `value` of `input`.

Comment: I edited my answer to imitate more your code in that respect (using an input rather than a div for the watch). I didn't put lot of effort to imitate exactly your code as far as DOM and style is concerned. But I see nothing in it that make it fundamentaly different (but, of course, for the fact to measure time rather than count calls). So, if your code was updating fields and make than persistent that is probably because of something done behind the scene by a library/platform you use. But I gess that the simple fact to put the time as value of a field rather than a textContent

Comment: of an input might allow that (at least, it is the only difference I see from my code from yours, style excluded).

Answer (score 1):

To add the ability to make the stopwatch appear to continue progressing rather than pausing even if the user moves to a different tab, you can leverage the web browser's visibilitychange event.

This is the code adding the visibilitychange event to the code:

```js
let startBtn = document.getElementById('start');
let stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop');
let resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
let timeY = document.getElementById('timey');

let minute = 00;
let second = 00;
let count = 00;

// Add
let startDate = new Date();

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'none';
};

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    timer = true;
    stopWatch();

    document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'none';
});

stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    timer = false;
    document.getElementById('start').innerHTML = "Continue";
    document.getElementById('stop').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'inline';
});

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    timer = false;

    minute = 0;
    second = 0;
    count = 0;

    document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "00";

    document.getElementById('acf-field_651d01208c082').value = "00:00:00";
});

function timeCalculation() {
    let nowDate = new Date();
    nowDate.setMinutes(nowDate.getMinutes() - startDate.getMinutes());
    nowDate.setSeconds(nowDate.getSeconds() - startDate.getSeconds());
    nowDate.setMilliseconds(nowDate.getMilliseconds() - startDate.getMilliseconds());

    let minute = nowDate.getMinutes();
    let second = nowDate.getSeconds();
    let count = parseInt(nowDate.getMilliseconds() / 10);
    
    return [minute, second, count];
}

function stopWatch() {
    if (timer) {
        count++;

        if (count == 100) {
            second++;
            count = 0;
        }

        if (second == 60) {
            minute++;
            second = 0;
        }


        let minString = minute;
        let secString = second;
        let countString = count;


        if (minute < 10) {
            minString = "0" + minString;
        }

        if (second < 10) {
            secString = "0" + secString;
        }

        if (count < 10) {
            countString = "0" + countString;
        }

        document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = minString;
        document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = secString;
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = countString;
    
        document.getElementById('acf-field_651d01208c082').value = minString+":"+secString+":"+countString;
    
    
        setTimeout(stopWatch, 10);
    }
}

// Add
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange);

function handleVisibilityChange() {
    if (document.visibilityState === "visible") { 
        if (timer) { 
            [minute, second, count] = timeCalculation();
        } else {
            startDate = new Date();
        }
    }
}

jQuery('#acf-group_651d0120348fc').insertAfter('#submitdiv');
```

```css
#acf-field_651d01208c082 {cursor: help;text-align: center;font-family: Vazirmatn UI, sans-serif !important;border: 0px;font-size: 19px;letter-spacing: 4px;background: transparent !important;background: #fff0 !important;}
#buttons #start {background: #4CAF50;color: #FFF;border: 1px solid #4CAF50;}
#buttons #start:hover {background: #409743;color: #FFF;border: 1px solid #4CAF50;}
#buttons #stop {display:none;background: #e73e77;color: #FFF;border: 1px solid #e73e77;}
#buttons #stop:hover {background: #c13b68;color: #FFF;border: 1px solid #e73e77;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timey" style="text-align: center;direction: ltr !important;font-size: 0px !important;font-size: 0.01px !important;visibility: hidden;">
            <span class="digit" id="min">
                00</span>
            <span class="txt">:</span>
            <span class="digit" id="sec">
                00</span>
            <span class="txt">:</span>
            <span class="digit" id="count">
                00</span>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons" style="text-align: center;">
            <button type="button" class="button" id="start">start</button>
            <button type="button" class="button" id="stop" style="display: none;">stop</button>
            <button type="button" class="button" id="reset">reset</button>
        </div>

<input type="text" id="acf-field_651d01208c082" name="acf[field_651d01208c082]" placeholder="00:00:00" readonly="">
```

Comment: That is still accumulating a counter. At least when tab is visible. So time measurement is still inaccurate (accumulating an error also). Except when time is not visible (which means that your version of stopwatch is more accurate when we don't look at it). It has its avantage tho: I guess `new Date` takes more cpu than just accumulating a counter. So, maybe it is better, for display, to just count that way, and update real time, say, only once per second. But that is now what you are doing. For now you are measuring with a counter.

Comment: Which means that, if, for another reason than visibility, we miss some `stopWatch` calls (for example, because the PC is busy with some heavy task), we stay behind.